# Removing map element by value

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I'll keep this brief.

I am trying to keep a map between strings and object pointers, and as such, I use std::map. I have a manager that's a global class that keeps track of the map, and whenever an object's destructor is called, it tells the manager that it has been deleted.

The only way I can think of is to search through the map for the object. Is there an efficient STL solution to this problem? Does a map that is efficient at searching by key as well exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No there is not an efficient way of doing this with std::map other than iterating through comparing the values.

However most of the time the key for a value is computable from the value itself.  For example using the Name property of a Person object as the key.  Is it possible for the manager to store a list of key / value pairs as opposed to the value itself.  This would solve your problem without having to rewrite a new algorithm.

Or alternatively you could keep a reverse map on the manager class.  Essentially value to key.  That way you could use it to compute the key to remove later on.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think of having the object store the key itself. Definitely a better solution than having a second map.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at [SGI's documentation for the STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html),

> Map has the important property that
>   inserting a new element into a map
>   does not invalidate iterators that
>   point to existing elements. Erasing an
>   element from a map also does not
>   invalidate any iterators, except, of
>   course, for iterators that actually
>   point to the element that is being
>   erased.

So you can store an iterator into the map inside your object, and use that as a constant-time lookup key when you need to go delete its entry.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Boost Multi-Index Containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) library.

Comment: Note that you need both keys and values to be unique in order to use a bidirectional map.  std::map only requires unique keys.